# accessing session after login and logout in feature spec

Tags: session, rspec, capybara, rspec-rails, capybara-webkit

I want to be able test that after logout the session is invalid.
For this I want to check that after login, session exists and i want to get the session details. After logout the session no longer exists.

One way i can think of is to check that session exists in redis after login and doesn't exist in redis after logout. But I'm not sure how to do this.

Please do let me know if there is any other approach that I can try.

Here is what I have so far:

```
scenario "session is invalidated on logout", js:true do
    login_page.login('abcxyz@test.com', 'usfyguysgugy')
    @user = User.find_by(email: 'abcxyz@test.com')
    page.get_rack_session
end
```

But this gives error:

```
Failure/Error: page.get_rack_session
     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find visible xpath "//body/pre"
```

I have also tried using 
redis.keys('*'), but wasn't successful.

Any lead on how to access the session would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You're writing feature specs, you shouldn't be accessing the DB/redis/etc directly in those type of tests. Feature tests are all about testing what a user can and cannot do, so to verify that logout ends the session, verify that the logout link no longer exists, and a login link now exists. Something like

```
scenario "session is invalidated on logout", js:true do
  login_page.login('abcxyz@test.com', 'usfyguysgugy')
  click_link 'logout'
  expect(page).not_to have_link('logout')
  expect(page).to have_link('login')
end
```

If you truly want to verify the details of a session stored in redis, that would be done in a controller or request spec.

Comment: I have this in place but I also want to check the session. either the current_user session or in the redis. I can have a request test.

Comment: @aria - Then writing a controller spec or request spec would be the place to test that, where you have access to all the inner workings of the app. It's not something you should be testing in a feature spec.  Generally if it's hard to access some info you think you want in a test it means you're testing the wrong thing.

Comment: How can I access session from request spec? can you point me to any examples.